# Returning duplicates in a list using a for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The below code I did while trying to return the first number that appears twice, I am trying to learn code by myself.

I then decided what if I attempt to return all the duplicate integers in the list 1, 7, 8 but I am struggling to come up with a solution to do so. I tried to scan this website and other websites but I am not finding something that explains what I should be researching.

If someone would be so kind as to point in the right direction of what I should be reading to figure it out that would be great.  I am attempting to use a for loop for this solution as I need a lot of practice with loops in python.

If you take the time thank you, I hope this question makes sense : )

Code Snippet is below that I am struggling with:

```
def return_not_unique(list):
    for index, element in enumerate(list):
        for y in list[1+index:]:
            if element == y:
                return element

print(return_not_unique([1, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 1, 6]))
```

Comment: Do you miss the function *signature* on the first line?  Please don't put your *updated* ideas in the comments, put it the Problem.

Comment: Also, don't name variables after builtins, because that shadows the builtin. In this case, the builtin class `list` is inaccessible inside your function `return_not_unique`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hint: in Python there exists a `set` datatype that, if applied to a list e.g. `set(list_name)`, will store the unique values within a list.

Now that you have the unique values, consider how you would also store the number of times each unique value is seen in the list.